# show and remove same button in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I have one `UIButton`. Now I add button on `Subview` :-

```
UIButton* button4 = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame4];
[button4 setBackgroundImage:image3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button4 setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
[button4 addTarget:self action:@selector(Nofication:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

- (void)Nofication:(id)sender
{
    share=[[UIView alloc]init];
    share.frame=CGRectMake(300, 60, 130, 100);
    [self.view addSubview:share];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                     animations:^{
                         share.frame =CGRectMake(180, 50, 130, 100); // its final location
                     }];
    share.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];

    login=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    login.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 130, 50);
    [login setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"login.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [login addTarget:self action:@selector(asubmit:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [share addSubview:login];
    login.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor];

    policies=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    policies.frame=CGRectMake(0, 50, 130, 50);
    [policies setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Policies.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [policies addTarget:self action:@selector(apolicies:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

    [share addSubview:policies];
  }
```

When I click button it's open subview working nice. But now I need if subview is showing in that time click button it's need to hidden subview. If `subview` is not showing in that time when I click button it's need to show `subview`. So Please give me any idea about it.

How to Show and Hidden same `UIButton`

thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what asked?
Where subview is the view (or UIButton) you are trying to hide if shown, and show if hidden.

```
[subview setHidden:![subview isHidden]];
```

Edit : 
In your `Notification` function :

```
// Be sure that the view is loaded, maybe load it at a different place or use a boolean

if([subview isHidden]){
    [subview setHidden:false];
}else{
    [subview setHidden:true];
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply if click button open subview.if click again i need to hidden subview

Answer (score 1):

There is a `hidden` property on UIView. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/hidden

```
if (button.isHidden) {
    button.hidden = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `button4.selected = !button4.selected` in `Nofication:` method.
Then you can check `button4.isSelected` and hide/show subview with `hidden` property

Hope it helps.